# Authentication and Authorization in asmx webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asmx, webmethod

I have two asmx services one for `Account(Login,Register,Logout)` and the other `Report(adminreport,userreport)`.

Now I want to authorize the access only to **report.asmx** based on the login in account.asmx.

I have done it in **global.ascx**

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Context.Request.Url.Segments.Length > 2 && Context.Request.Url.Segments[Context.Request.Url.Segments.Length - 1] != "Login")
        { 
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 403;
        var httpApplication = sender as HttpApplication;
        httpApplication.CompleteRequest();
        }
    }
```

I know doing this is not good way. but my problem was to restrict  `Application_AuthenticateRequest` for **account.asmx**.

I have tried location in **web.cfg** and it didnot work and I'm calling the service from ajax.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Yeah, i know its much easier with WCF or the WebAPi 2. But i am stuck with asmx( for some corporate reason).

Comment: The comment wasn't only for you, but also for anyone else who reads this question. Including your corporate reasons.